# Internet Explorer 11 won't accept variables in modal speedbump

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a site that is using Kylefox's Jquery-Modal library to have essentially 'speedbumps' when clicking on external links on the site.  The issue is the 'speedbump' modal is coded only once, but I need to swap out the external link depending on which external link a user clicks on.   This works great in all browsers except IE11

I've tried the method outlined in Kylefox's github, 
I've even put console.log and alerts in the modal.BEFORE_OPEN action and it doesn't appear to be firing at all in IE11.

```
$('#externallink').on($.modal.BEFORE_OPEN, function(event, modal) {
    var url = modal.$anchor.attr('data-href');
    $('#externallink #enterance').attr('href',url);
});
```

IE11 isn't seeing any sort of event, the console shows no activity, which is strange because the modal IS opening, but the external link is not populating in the speedbump modal.

Comment: Your above code sample is not enough to produce the issue with IE 11 and other browsers. Please try to post any working example which we can run in IE 11 and other browsers to see the difference in the result to understand the issue properly. If possible than also try to post the link of the documentation you are trying to refer for developing this code.

Comment: I am using [jquery modal] (https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) and the actual modal code is on page and looks like this.

`<div class="alertbox modal" id="externallink">Warning, this is an external link.  Please press ok to continue<a href="" id="enterance" target="_blank" class="cta">Ok</a><a href="#close" id="cancel" rel="modal:close">Cancel</a></div>` .

Comment: I've created a codepen
https://codepen.io/benpavlov/pen/WNeRKxG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to test your sample code with **IE 11 (11.471.17134.0)** version and find that your code is working fine with IE 11 same as it is working with any other browser.

I also try to print **HREF** value of **enterance** and it prints properly.

Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="#externallink" data-href="http://www.google.com" rel="modal:open">External Link 1</a><br />

<a href="#externallink" data-href="http://www.duckduckgo.com" rel="modal:open">External Link 2</a><br />

<div class="alertbox modal" id="externallink">Warning, this is an external link. Please press ok to continue<br />
<a href="" id="enterance" target="_blank" class="cta">Ok</a>  
<a href="#close" id="cancel" rel="modal:close">Cancel</a></div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#externallink').on($.modal.BEFORE_OPEN, function(event, modal) {
    var url = modal.$anchor.attr('data-href');
    $('#enterance').attr('href',url);
console.log("HREF = " + $('#enterance').attr('href'));
}); 
});  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

I suggest you to use my tested example and try to directly run in IE 11 to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Found the issue; somewhere else up my codestream is causing issues.   Thank you for your help